# TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp

I am trying to connect to server, Here is my piece of code

```
import socket
HOST = '192.168.10.11'
PORT = 5060
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

I get the following `TimeoutError`:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:Trails/calltest.py", line 7, in <module>
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
   TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I tried if the port is working or not

```
~# nmap -p 5060 -sU -P0 192.168.10.11
```

I got the reply

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-05-11 19:44 IST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.10.11
Host is up.
PORT     STATE         SERVICE
5060/udp open|filtered sip
```

Why am I not able to connect? Any help appreciated!

Comment: On the last line of your example code, don't you mean `s.connect((HOST,PORT))`?

Comment: then how to connect ?

Comment: In *nmap* output: "*5060/ __udp__ open*". You might want to use `socket.SOCK_DGRAM`.

Comment: Thank you @CristiFati. I am a bit late in understanding the networking concepts. I was trying with TCP module, I changed to UDP and its working.

Comment: Nice to hear you got it working!